# Atmosphere framework does not work on Openshift with payara

Tags: jsf, openshift, atmosphere

my application use the **Atmosphere** framework for the communication between the server and the client. I can configure different transport mechanisms which can be used with the atmosphere framework (Websocket, polling, long-polling, SSE..).
Locally, the atmosphere framework works fine which all the transport mechanisms but on **Openshift** it doesn't work. (I want it actually to work either with SSE or Websocket).
The problem is that I see that the status is 101 in the browser debugger.[101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dag51.png)

But in the frames I do not see the data being received and I cannot see the pushes are coming up in the app. (I have to refresh the page to see the changes)

[frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vf6Vk.png)

PS: I am using JSF as front end framework.

I don't know what could be the cause of that problem. I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: How do you test it locally?

Comment: I send requests/pushes to the app and I can see that the data are updated successfully and that the pushes are there. I check that with the browser console and network. Did I answer your question ?

Comment: can you get atmosphere to work in a non-jsf page? if not, it is not jsf related.